# Kali Linux: Run penetration test and generate report for particular site?

Tags: kali-linux

I am new in Kali Linux and recently one of my jobs is to use Kali Linux to scan a newly developed site and see if there are any security issue.

And after going through some courses I found that, in Kali Linux there are a lot of tools that you can use to do scanning, but it seems that there is no a single tool, at least for a beginner, to just "Scan a website and generate a report".

Can it be done?

Comment: Kali is just a Linux distribution. It's the tools that perform the scanning (and then the reporting). Why is someone insisting that you use "Kali" to scan something?

Comment: So, if you remove Kali from the question, you are left with "what tools can a beginner use to scan a website?" And that's a little too broad to answer. It depends on what you want to achieve and what your skills are.

Comment: My suggestion is that you use all the tools in the standard collection in Kali. I'm not sure why you want a single tool to meet all of your needs.

Comment: Thank you all.  Maybe I misunderstood the role of Kali Linux and that's why I ask if I can use that to do scanning.  But thank you all for your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too broad question, but I'll mention some tools that I've found useful and easy to begin with:

- [Netsparker](https://www.netsparker.com/)

  Good tool that helps with **testing SQL Injection** and **Cross-site Scripting**. Check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPTJQ.png) image for a report example.
- [Nessus](https://www.tenable.com/products/nessus/nessus-professional)

  Amazing tool due to its ease of use, installation and activation might be difficult, but it's a good tool to try. It can help you with **scanning** html5 and Ajax web applications, along with **host scanning**. Check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IweFc.jpg) image for a report example.
- [W3af](http://w3af.org/take-a-tour)

  Another good tool for **testing web applications**, it also can helps with HTTP basic and digest authentication testing. Not sure if there's a good report generating.

You can check [this](https://www.guru99.com/top-5-penetration-testing-tools.html) article for many other tools.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you.  Maybe I misunderstood the concept/role of Kali Linux and that's why i ask that question.  But thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, please consider marking the question as answered if you've found what you're seeking. Thanks.